# How are these two angles equal?

Tags: geometry

I am reading about the geometrical derivation of the centripetal acceleration formula.  And the only thing I don't understand is the angles.

For example, here is a picture.

[image]

The assertion is that angle $BCD$ = $\theta$

However, I cannot understand this at all.  The lines aren't parallel.  There's no way they can prove this.  What am I not understanding or missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that $OACB$ is a 4 sided polygon, so all interior angles add up to $360^{\circ}$. We have that $\angle OAC=\angle OBC =90^{\circ}$. Hence $\angle ACB=180-\theta$ and hence $\angle BCD=\theta$.